# How to split a string from UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, uitextfield

I have a UITextField as following:

```
_itemTextField = [[UITextField alloc];
```

This UITextField may contain item number only ex: "11321" or item number and size ex: "11321-XS" or "12355-40".

I want to extract the item and size (if it's available) separately in two different variables, as following:

```
NSString *itemNumber = @"11321";
NSString *itemSize   = @"XS";
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *str = @"11115-ex";

if([str containsString:@"-"]){
NSArray * arr =[str componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
    NSString *first = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *second = [arr objectAtIndex:1];

     NSLog(@"Return String %@  %@",first,second);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Return String %@",str);
}
```